# Swift - UITableView Frozen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableView` called `EditCalendarParticipationViewController` that segues via push in a storyboard to another `UITableView` called `PlayerParticipationViewController`.

The problem is, when I tap on a cell in `EditPlayerParticipationController` and perform the segue, it works fine, and goes to `PlayerParticipationViewController`. But when I dismiss via modal or back button on `PlayerParticipationViewController`, the cell I tapped is still highlighted on the orginal table view (`EditPlayerParticipationViewController`) and the entire table view is frozen.

Here is some code:

First View Controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueID,
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as? PlayerParticipationDetailViewController,
            let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath {
            destinationVC.playerCalendar = self.playerCalendars[indexPath.row]
            destinationVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        // Reference the selected indexpath
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueID, sender: nil)
    }
```

Is there something I should be adding in the second view controller to fix this issue

Comment: I suggest using the debugger to pause the program while the table is frozen and investigate what is happening on the main thread.

Comment: You are setting a delegate. What does that delegate do? What do you have in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` in the first view controller?